# How users of the website can delete values of inputs?

Tags: php

I am working on the page, on which users can edit information about them. When they open the page it shows them all information inside inputs.

When they try to change it, I want to be sure they will not submit empty inputs, but values from data base into them and when I delete them I shows error page instead of error message, because it doesn't delete an old value. (it updates my database if I put something new.

```
<form method="post" action="update.php">
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>">
<?php echo $name_err; ?>
<input type="submit" value="SAVE"/>
</form>
```

UPDATE.PHP

```
  $name_err = "";


 // Processing form data when form is submitted
  if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

  // Validate name
    if(empty(trim($_POST["name"]))){
     $name_err = "Can't be empty!."; }
```

and then...

```
  if(empty($name_err)) {

    // Prepare an insert statement
    $sql = "UPDATE `users` SET `name`= (?) WHERE user_id=45";
```

Comment: @Progrock thank you for your answer! The mistake is only here, I wanted to translate those names into english, because I wanted to be clear with everything. I updated my question. :)

Comment: Try and edit your question and describe your problem, the steps you take to produce it, your desired outcome, and the actual outcome / error /problem.

Comment: There is no error in error logs.

Comment: Perhaps you have error_reporting turned off.  You'll need to clarify your problem, it is too vague as it stands.